# How to check whether a string contains at least one alphabet in java?

Tags: java, string

I want such a validation that My String must be contains at least one alphabet.

I am using the following:

```
String s = "111a11";
boolean flag = s.matches("%[a-zA-Z]%");
```

flag gives me `false`  even though `a` is in my string `s`

Comment: Don't use %. That is for SQL LIKE, not regexp. Use `.*` instead So just `s.matches(".*[a-zA-Z].*");`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The regular expression you want is `[a-zA-Z]`, but you need to use the `find()` method.

This page will let you test regular expressions against input.

[Regular Expression Test Page](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm)

and here you have a Java Regular Expressions tutorial.

[Java Regular Expressions tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: If you consider other languages, you could use `boolean m = str.matches(".*[\\p{L}]+.*]")`

Answer (score 104):

You can use `.*[a-zA-Z]+.*` with `String.matches()` method.

```
boolean atleastOneAlpha = s.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*");
```

Comment: can we check the min and max number of characters in this regex?

Comment: You post a question for it.

Comment: Man I know this is several years old but thank you guys so much! Been looking all over for the proper regex expression and this is exactly what I needed. I'm going to brush up on regex expressions but man I was struggling. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin

```
val inputString = "Hello123"
val containsAlphabets = inputString.matches(Regex(".*[a-zA-Z].*"))
if (containsAlphabets) {
println("The input string contains alphabetic characters.")
} else {
println("The input string does not contain alphabetic characters.")
}
```