# How to write the if condition for this situation?

Tags: java, if-statement

I need to set an error for a password field with the condition "Only 2~22 characters and symbols , _ - are allowed."

But I am a little stuck here.

Here is what I got so far:

```
if(
  !(editText.length() >= 2 && editText.length() <= 22 ) ||
    !(editText.contains("-") || editText.contains("_") || editText.contains(","))
  ) {
  //set error message
}
```

But the problem is that if I input a symbol other than , _ or -, the error message still doesn't show. For the input length, the error message shows as it should though.

Comment: Look into the string matches method : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14278602/792238

Comment: Have you tried regex?

Comment: Just tried this editText.matches("^[a-zA-Z\-,_]{2,22}$") but it shows illegal character...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java, use :

```
editText.matches("^[A-Za-z,_\\-]{2,22}$");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `||` or commands for the hyphen, underscore, and comma are making it that the user *has* to include at least one of each of those characters.

You also aren't checking for a list of valid characters.  A-Z?  0-9? a-z?  You will want to look at the [Package java.util.regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) package or iterate over the String and check each character.

Answer (score 1):

There is the problem with ur logic, use && after <= 22 ) in place of ||
Try this:

```
if(!((editText.length() >= 2 && editText.length() <= 22 ) && (editText.contains("-") || editText.contains("_") || editText.contains(","))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use Regex for this while researching I came accross [Regex Library for Strong Password](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=strong%20password&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

You can implement below regex for your purpose

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[a-z]).{2,22}$
```

### Explanation:

```
^                         Start anchor
(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])        Ensure string has uppercase letters.
(?=.*[!@#$&*])            Ensure string has one special case letter.
(?=.*[a-z]) Ensure string has lowercase letters.
.{2,22}                   Ensure string is of 2 char long and Max of 22.
$                         End anchor.
```

### Implementation

```
if(editText.matches(^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[a-z]).{2,22}$))
{
  //set error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a regex.

But otherwise, you'll need to iterate through the string to insure that *no* character is < 'a' or > 'z' and not ('_' or '-').

As far as the "length" check, this might be a bit more readable:

```
(editText.length() < 2 || editText.length() > 22 )
```

But again - I'd encourage you to consider using a regex:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html