# Find all keywords of a text file that have at least one letter by using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regular expression to remove all tokens of a text file that do not have at least one letter. I used OpenNLP tokenizer for extracting tokens of my text file.For instance, tokens *90-87, 65@7, ---, 8/0, ?* are removed from given text.

I tried to follow these pages [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238491/check-if-string-contains-only-letters) ,[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278170/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-at-least-one-alphabet-in-java) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper); but I could not find the expression that I want. For example, the following code remove token *anti-age, mid-november*.

```
String[] tokens = t.getTokens(sen);

for (String word : tokens) 
    if((!isstopWord(word)) && word.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
          bufferedw.append(word+"\n");
```

But, I do not know how to prevent removing tokens like anti-age.

where is the problem?

Comment: When you say *"at least one character"* do you mean "at least one **letter**"? Because `9`, `-`, `@`, and `/` are all Unicode characters too.

Comment: Instead of an example, please specify what kind of tokens you need to keep, i.e. formulate the requirements. BTW, perhaps, you are looking for `word.matches("\\S*\\pL+\\S*")`.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I mean one letter.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want tokens which have at least one letter.

Comment: http://ideone.com/f3RR8i? Like that?

Comment: Please explain "tokens". Is `a+b` one token or 3?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you mean I should change my regular expression to this one `matches("\\S*\\pL+\\S*")`

Comment: Well, `matches("\\S*\\pL\\S*")` is enough. `\pL` matches any Unicode letter. `\S` matches a non-whitespace character.

Comment: @Arkadiy it is three token a, +, b. I use openNLP for tokenizing my text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[a-zA-Z]+` expression matches a string that only consists of one or more ASCII letters. It does not allow hyphens, apostrophes, etc.

To match a string containing no spaces and at least one *letter*, you can use

```
word.matches("\\S*\\pL\\S*")
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/f3RR8i)

The `\S*` pattern matches zero or more non-whitespace characters and `\pL` matches any Unicode letter.