# Using the indexOf() method, is there a way for me to return the first index in a string that is an alphabetical letter? Java

Tags: java

Title. I'm new to this site sorry if it's bad question. I'm trying to make it so that my method returns -1 if there isn't an alphabetical letter in the string. I already set up a way to iterate through the string but now I need to know how to see if it returns true if it finds ANY alphabetical letter in the string and -1 if not.

Comment: Probably not using `indexOf` but a regular expression should work

Comment: try casting to int?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues, cast what to an `int`? How would this approach help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a string contains at least one alphabet in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278170/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-at-least-one-alphabet-in-java)

Comment: Well, the duplicate I suggested depends upon whether your statement of returning "true" if it has a character, not if you want to return the specific index of the first alphabetical character. So please specify exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: whatever that string is, if a cast to int works it ain't letter, its a number.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues Casting strings to int is not possible in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the index of the first letter in a string, use a regular expression:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```
static int indexOfLetter(String input) {
    String regex = "[a-zA-Z]";
    //         or: "\\p{Alpha}";  // same as [a-zA-Z]
    //         or: "\\p{L}";      // all unicode letters
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
    if (m.find())
        return m.start();
    return -1;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(indexOfLetter("123456789")); // prints: -1
System.out.println(indexOfLetter("12345ABCD")); // prints: 5
System.out.println(indexOfLetter("@#$XYZ%^&")); // prints: 3
```

If you use the `\p{L}` regex, it'll find accented letters too.

```
static int indexOfLetter(String input) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}").matcher(input);
    return (m.find() ? m.start() : -1);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(indexOfLetter("...ñ...")); // 3  'LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE' (U+00F1)
System.out.println(indexOfLetter("..ß.."));   // 2  'LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S' (U+00DF)
System.out.println(indexOfLetter(".Δ."));     // 1  'GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA' (U+0394)
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you're not allowed to use regex ("[not allow me to use additional import statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878710/using-the-indexof-method-is-there-a-way-for-me-to-return-the-first-index-in-a/52878967?noredirect=1#comment92672692_52878967)"), a simple search loop calling [`Character.isLetter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-char-) will do:

```
static int indexOfLetter(String input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        if (Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i)))
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

That does support Unicode letters, but not surrogate pairs. Given the rarity of letters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), that's probably not an issue. If it is, the following change will support those too:

```
static int indexOfLetter(String input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i = input.offsetByCodePoints(i, 1))
        if (Character.isLetter(input.codePointAt(i)))
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I am doing an assignment that does not allow me to use additional import statements. If there is no other way then I must be approaching the assignment the wrong way.

Comment: Thank you so much.